# Action event of button is not fiered whlie ids are generaed manually in jsf

Tags: jsf

When i manually generating id of button action event of button is not fiered,but when i don't generate it manually it works properly( action event is invoked).my code is below.can any one tell me where the problem is.

.xhtml

```
<c:forEach  items="#{bean.mylist1}" var="i">
    <c:forEach  items="#{bean.mylist}" var="j">
          <p:commandButton id="id_#{bean.genid()}"  action="#{bean.btnmethode()}">
          </p:commandButton>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

bean

```
 public Integer genid()
    {
        return  inc++;
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need custom button ID's ?

Comment: yes, because i am using that ID's in jquery.actually i am processing all buttons in jquery with only one click of button.

Comment: if you use CSS selectors instead of ids in your jQuery, your problem would be solved.

Comment: You can use a `styleClass` as selector instead. For your problem, I suspect that ID's generated are not the same between JSF phases, how is your variable `inc` is initialized?

Comment: i have edited my question.as you can see in code i am using nested for loops.using this loops i am generating table of buttons.so when i click on one button only that row's all button should change their css.all buttons have same css so using styleclass i can not process only that particular row.so i want create custom IDs for processing only that row of buttons.'inc' is intialized with '0'.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't give the id for the button based on the too loops for exemple:

```
<c:forEach  items="#{bean.mylist1}" var="i" varStatus="loop1">
    <c:forEach  items="#{bean.mylist}" var="j" varStatus="loop2">
          <p:commandButton id="bt#{loop1.index}delim#{loop2.index}"  action="#{bean.btnmethode()}">
          </p:commandButton>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: i have tried your solution.it does not worked for me because my both list is made up of objects.

Comment: it gives me error " The class 'java.lang.Byte' does not have the property 'index'."

Comment: @user3652380 you must use varStatus variables for ID's not var.

Comment: @Dhouha the ID can be repeated example loop 1 index 1, loop 2 index 11 will give ID 111, loop 2 index 1, loop 1 index 11 will also give ID 111. You should add a delimiter between indexes.

Comment: @user3652380, you should use varStatus not var